# How can I create a semi automatic TNT cannon in Minecraft which does not need reloading?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Suppose I have a hill or a mountain I wish to demolish. I created a cannon using the classic recipe so I can do this task:

[image: TNT cannon]

My problem is that reloading is quite cumbersome. I know that I can manufacture cobblestone using lava and water. **Is there some way to manufature TNT somehow**? If i need a mod for this it is not a problem!

*So my goal is to be able to fire a primed TNT by pressing a button and without the need of reloading.*

Comment: not without a mod you can't

Comment: "If i need a mod for this it is not a problem!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now completely possible if you have access to [command blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block).  The key difference is that you can use the command blocks to `/summon` some `PrimedTNT` all in one spot, and all with very short fuses.

For instance in three command blocks, you could summon the cannon charge at 0, 0:

```
summon PrimedTNT 0 64 0 {Fuse:5}
```

Changing the Y value to something appropriate for your environment.  In a fourth command block, you would then summon your "cannon ball":

```
summon PrimedTNT 1 65 0 {Fuse:100}
```

The `Fuse` data tag is measured in redstone ticks, i.e. tenths of a second, and have a limit of 127 (signed 8-bit number / Java `byte`).

[image: TNT Cannon Running]

Comment: This is **AWESOME**! What mod do I need to get my hands on command blocks?

Comment: You don't.  You do need cheats enabled for single player, but that can be accomplished by opening the game to LAN.  Simply issue `/give @p command_block 64` to give yourself a stack of them.

Comment: What version of Minecraft do I need?

Comment: The block has been around since about 1.4, but I'm not sure when `summon` was added.  Somewhat recently I think.

Comment: One more question: How can you fire that far?

Comment: It depends on the number of charge TNTs (here it's only 3), and that gets you I think to the first crater hat you can see.  There's several craters after that, some beyond the render distance.

Comment: Ok, I found out that you can actually give a `Motion` parameter to your TNT which describes the speed and direction.

Comment: Yeah, that's another way.  It's more complicated, which is why I didn't bother to do it that way.  That would give you more finesse as to the location of the shot, though.

Answer (score 2):

Zisteau created a [TNT magazine](http://youtu.be/akC7qePORWw) that could be used for dropping TNT.  Multiple magazines, arranged correctly, could be used to create a TNT cannon.

This might not be the best use of resources (or time), unless you're willing to go into creative and/or use MCEdit.  In which case, why would you be worried about a mountain?

Comment: This is not generating TNT. This will run out of ammo eventually. As I stated in my question I want something that doesn't need a reload.

Comment: @AdamArold: There is no way to generate TNT as far as I know.  I must have skipped over that part of your question.

Answer (score -8):

There is no way at all to do this