# How can I summon TNT without causing damage to blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to summon a TNT block that will cause damage to mobs. However, I don't want it to damage or break blocks. Is there any way that I can do this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: This isn't possible with TNT, however, this *is* possible using creepers with a fuse time of 0. If you want to replace the functionality of TNT, then this can also be done by looking for a TNT entity with a fuse of x, then summoning a creeper there with fuse 0 and killing the TNT. This does require mobGriefing=false, though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I turn off TNT block damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191684/how-can-i-turn-off-tnt-block-damage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method #1**:

On a **fast** Redstone clock / using Repeat Command blocks, put this command:

```
/execute @e[type=PrimedTnt] ~ ~ ~ summon Creeper ~ ~ ~ {powered:1}
```

Then, with a Comparator, execute this command to kill the TNT:

```
/kill @e[type=PrimedTnt]
```

**Note**: Before you do this, you would have to run this command:

```
/gamerule mobGriefing false
```

**Method #2**:

Repeatedly run these commands in Command blocks (repeat as fast as you can):

```
/execute @e[type=PrimedTnt] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"RudolfJelinek"}

/execute @e[type=PrimedTnt] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:water
```

And when the Comaparator leading from one of the CMD blocks above does not output signal, execute these commands:

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:air 

/kill @e[name=RudolfJelinek]
```

Comment: This is what I want! But can I know why you need to summon ArmorStand?

Comment: The armour stand is there so you can execute commands at it even when all other entities are gone. If the armour stand wasn't there, there would be no way to clean up the water after the tnt exploded (unless you knew the exact cords everytime).

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Unionhawk's comment:

you should run three commands one after the other:

```
Do gamerule mobGriefing = false**
```

1 tick delay

```
Summon Creeper fuse 0 at Tnt
```

3 ticks delay

```
Do gamerule mobgriering = true
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier solution to this, relying on the rule that immerged TNT doesn't explode blocks but do damage to entities :

1. Place a water block :

> setblock X Y Z minecraft:water

2. Summon an instant-exploding TNT at this location :

> summon minecraft:tnt X Y Z {Fuse:0}

You can remove the water block afterwards, but after a little delay, otherwise TNT would explode and destroy blocks.